# Comparação de algoritmos de pesquisa dentro de cadeias de texto

Tags: string, algoritmo

Estou tentando implementar os seguintes algoritmos para pesquisa de expressões dentro de cadeias de textos em Java: Knuth-Morris-Pratt (KMP), Força-bruta, Boyer-Moore e Levenshtein

Como poderia mostrar a similaridade obtida para realizar um comparativo entre os algoritmos, e ver qual oferece melhor desempenho?

Comment: Não entendi o foça bruta para comparar texto. No mais, talvez você possa criar uma lista de strings e plotar o valor de 'similaridade' de cada método, para cada par de strings da lista. Talvez comparar o tempo de execução. Se eu fosse fazer, talvez para começar eu faria cada análise (de cada par) por cada método, e daria uma nota para cada um em função do desvio padrão dos resultados.

Comment: Os algoritmos referidos não são de comparação de textos mas sim de pesquisa de expressões dentro de uma cadeia de texto. Já editei.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um [profilador](https://netbeans.org/features/java/testing.html) para testar o tempo de execução dos algoritmos desenvolvidos, ou você pode testar o tempo total de execução.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
//SEU CÓDIGO... pode ser a instância de um objeto também  
long delay = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;  
System.out.println("O tempo de execução foi de: " + delay + " milissegundos");
```

Answer (score 1):

Para compará-los é preciso que eles se disponham a fazer a mesma coisa, você citou "comparação de texto", mas o termo está muito genérico, talvez o que você queira seja distância de edição: ou seja, qual o número mínimo de operações de adição, remoção e edição que são necessárias para sair da primeira string para a segunda.

Dito isso, se é esse o seu problema, e os algoritmos que você citou o resolvem. Você pode comparar os algoritmos assim: 1) para cada par de algoritmos que deu a melhor resposta (em caso de empate), verificar qual dele é mais eficiente, em tempo e memória; 2) em caso de respostas diferentes, o que deu menor número de operações como resposta (lembrando, tem que estar correto).

A comparação de tempo pode ser feita de forma informal, como sugerida pelo @Maicon Herverton, ou mais formalmente utilizando análise assintótica.

Já o consumo de memória é um resultado direto do tamanho das estruturas de dados que estás usando em cada algoritmo.